# How do I add a field to a document from the server in a publish without saving it?

Tags: meteor

I want to add and return a calculated field from a server Meteor.publish that doesn't actually persist in MongoDB. Is this possible? Something like where I format some markdown:

```
  Meteor.publish('recentEdits', function(pageId) {
    var edits, formattedContent;
    edits = WikiEdits.find({pageId: pageId}, {sort: {ts: -1},
      limit: RECENT_EDIT_LIMIT});
    edits.forEach(function(edit) {
      formattedContent = marked(edit.content);
      edit.formattedContent = formattedContent;
    });
    return edits;
  });
```

To the client it should seem like that `formattedContent` field came like any other, but it's not actually in MongoDB. Is this possible and if so what is the best way? Even if I should store the formattedContent, I would still like to know how to do this.

I tried using the `transform` option in `Meteor.Collection` and that only ran on the client, but I want this to happen from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [transform](http://docs.meteor.com/#find) option of the `find`

the only problem is that it is also executed on the client. If you can live with that, it's a solution.

Another option could be to add an [unmanaged collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections) on the client and get the contents from a [Meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods)

The local unmanaged collection will not be stored in the MongoDB you can call the `Meteor.method` from an `autorun` and `observe` will work on the local collection.

Comment: THe problem with the client is that I want to use a Npm.require module that doesn't exist on the client. I guess I could wrap that code in a `isServer`statement.

Comment: but then the field would be empty on the client